# How can I bring the input to the center?

Tags: html, css

How to get `<input type="text">` in the center? I want to make a login form but i cannot bring the input on the center

Comment: What does "in the center" mean? In the centre of what? (If you want to horizontally centre something, there are hundreds if not thousands of questions already coving that on this site)

Comment: In the html body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1

Wrap your `input` element in a `div` and set it's `text-align` to `center`

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input/>
</div>
```

---

#### Method 2

Set the `input` element's display to `block` and set its margins

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: putting it into a code snippet would be great